# NextJs - Function in API folder in pages gives 'res.status is not a function' error

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using NextJs and I'm trying to create a subscription form that sends data to MailChimp. However, I'm getting error which says

> res.status is not a function

This file is inside my `pages/api` directory. What might be going wrong?

```
    import { subscribe } from "../../lib/api";
const request = require("request");

export default async function subscribeWithEmail(req, res) {
  const { email, js } = req.body;

  const mcData = {
    members: [
      {
        email_address: email,
        status: "pending",
      },
    ],
  };
  const mcDataPost = JSON.stringify(mcData);
  const options = {
    url: "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/SECRET",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "auth APIKEY",
    },
    body: mcDataPost,
  };

  if (email) {
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (err) {
        res.json({ error: err });
      } else {
        if (js) {
          res.status(200).send({ message: "yay" });
        } else {
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: "Failed" });
  }
  //   res.status(200).json(data);
  return res.status(200);
}
```

Comment: you have multiple `res.status` calls , which line throws the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing your initial `res` variable.

```
    // you have another res here, which has nothing to do with Next.js res, but it is overriding it
    // So you need to rename it to something else, for example to "response"
    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
      console.log(response);
      if (err) {
        res.json({ error: err });
      } else {
        if (js) {
          res.status(200).send({ message: "yay" });
        } else {
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      }
    });
```